# Working on google maps in android not able to call SetOnItemClickListener Event

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am beginner in android and I am developing one module where user click on the AutocompleteTextView for the places. I have taken the code from the   https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android

Now i am able to get the Result in the form of List but i am not able to select the text from that autocomplete List.

![enter image description here][1]

As you can see i am getting the List but when i click on the selected list it's doing nothing means my setOnItemClickListener is not getting invoked.

My mainActivity code is like this

```
public class GoogleMap extends Activity{

private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_map);

   autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

   adapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_google_map);
   autoCompView.setAdapter(adapter);
   autoCompView.setThreshold(1);


   // when the user clicks an item of the drop-down list
   autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                               long arg3) {
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "MultiAutoComplete: " +
                           "you add color "+arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2),
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not invoked? Use logs instead of toasts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the "PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter-Object", but if you're implementing an AutocompleteTextView it's enough to add an ArrayAdapter with the desired (and in this case possible) results:

```
    String[] stringArray = { "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"};

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, stringArray);
    autoCompView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

So if you're clicking on an item of the list, the selected item is automatically adopted to the textfield, no need for an OnClickListener.

For more information see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

If you want your code automatically do some stuff if an item is selected you can use TextWatcher: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

```
    final TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher(){

    //Auto-generated methods & stuff...

    };

    autoCompView.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

Greetings